# Having problems getting server side processing to work with Datatables and MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

Hello we currently have an MVC4 application that is bringing in a lot of records with thumbnail images into a jQuery Datatables driven view. This of course is loading very slowly when it does a GET to load all the thumbnails. To solve this I'm trying to make it so it uses server-side processing and only gets 10 results at a time.

To do this I followed the Datatables documentation and changed the Javascript like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Create an array with the values of all the checkboxes in a column */
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function (settings, col) {
        return this.api().column(col, { order: 'index' }).nodes().map(function (td, i) {
            return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
        });
    }

    /* Initialise the table with the required column ordering data types */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.passes').dataTable({

            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "ajax": "/Pass/Datatable",



            "columns": [
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric "},
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
                { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" }
            ],

            "order": [[5, "desc"]]


        });
    });
});
```

This is getting an AJAX source from a method within the controller where I return a JSON result. I get the information from my SQL tables and then I use a Datatable parser that I found on Github to parse the information I am getting into JSON like this:

```
        public JsonResult Datatable(int passesPerPage, HttpRequest Request)
    {
        //default number of passes will be set to 10
        passesPerPage = 10;


        var passes = db.Cards.OrderBy(c => c.Vendor.Name); // fetch the data from data model
        passes.Take(passesPerPage); //Takes the number of passes requested per page so as not to overload the server
        var parser = new DataTablesParser<Card>(Request, passes); //pass the parser the data to parse it into JSON
        return Json(parser.Parse()); // have the parser parse the request parameters and return the Json Result

    }
```

When I test the webpage however it still loads all of the records and has no pagination features at all. I am wondering what exactly I am doing wrong here as I'm not getting any errors of any kind other than unintended behavior. If I could get any help as to how I should go about debugging this or if anyone can see what I am doing wrong I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: When I check the server error log this is the ASP.NET error I get back from my Datatable.

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String

And the line that is causing the error is this one:

Line 46:             return Json(parser.Parse()); // have the parser parse the request parameters and return the Json Result

Comment: if you are getting ajax error, then it might be because the ajax returned result is not in the format which your plugin is expecting. You need to dig deep in dataTables tutotial to know how to data with the format it is expecting...

Answer (score 0):

Do some changes in your datatable properties for pagination :

```
$('.passes').dataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "ajax": "/Pass/Datatable",
        "bDestroy": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "columns": [
            { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric " },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" },
            { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" }
        ],
        "order": [[5, "desc"]]
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still loading a lot more than 10 records, and I also get a confirmation box stating that there was an AJAX error with DataTables. I feel like there is something wrong what I am trying to pull in from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

At first, sorry for my English.
If this can help, then i can say, that **DataTablesParser** automatically takes data from **Request** and pars your data as you need. The Request from Datatables.js have some property as **start** and **length**(as i understand, it's needed property for Parser) (https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), and Dataparser takes this data for parsing your data as you need. So you don't need to do

```
var passes = db.Cards.OrderBy(c => c.Vendor.Name);
passes.Take(passesPerPage);
```

Just use:

```
public JsonResult Datatable()
{
    var parser = new DataTablesParser<Card>(Request, SomeIQueryableData); 
    return Json(parser.Parse()); 
}
```